# Re-using C++ functions by importing DLL in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I've general questions while importing a C++ created DLL into C#.

1) I've written C++ functions making use of pointers such as double pointers, array of pointers etc. 
e.g. `static int someFunc(char *var[])`
How do i re-use them as C# does not support pointers.

2) Do I need to expose all the functions through [DllImport()] in C#? i.e. I've a function called someFunc which calls other functions internally. Should I expose those functions too under 'DllImport'

3) Can anyone please explain why I require to handle the unmanaged code in C# especially when I import dlls from C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point 1 Answer:
use the unsafe keyword in function declaration in C#

```
static unsafe int someFunc(char* var[]);
```

point 2 Answer:
There is no need to import all functions. only import someFunc()

point 3 answer:
C# uses managed code which is type safe and refers to some valid memory location. However pointers as in C++ may or may not refer to any valid memory location. So you need to handle unmanaged code in C#.

Comment: Hi I'm using a datatype called DWORD which I've defined in a C++ headerfile that I include in my C++ DLL code. How to handle this? as DWORD is not visible in C#.

Comment: Please replace DWORD with System.Int32. If DWORD is unsigned then use System.UInt32.

Answer (score 0):

C# does support pointers in unsafe regions, however, you can also use IntPtr which is similar to C++'s void* DllImport with IntPtr as parameter or return value.

The correct thing to do, however, would be to use [marshaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s97shtze.aspx) to automatically translate char* to System.String and vise versa. (And to [translate an array of char* to an array of strings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17450/Marshal-an-Array-of-Zero-Terminated-Strings-or-Str).)